# Apache permission for php to run `git pull`

Tags: php, git, apache, ubuntu, vps

I'm running in trouble with my new VPS. I created a file `pull.php` with this code in my GIT folder:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('git pull');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

It was working fine on my shared hosting but on my VPS it's return null and no 'pull' command executed. When I change the command 'git pull' to 'git status' it's show result :

> On branch master
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>
> Untracked files:   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be
>   committed)
>
> info.php    pull.php    test.txt
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to
>   track)

My folder chmod to 777 and php seems can write on it properly. 'git pull' on SSH's fine. My server : Ubuntu 14.x, Apache2, php5

I would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: Check your error log. Also are you using ssh keys to auth to Git?

Comment: 777 is a lame excuse... you should really be executing PHP as a user and not 'apache' or 'nobody'. This would solve most of everyone's problems.

Comment: @arleslie , I enabled error_display but no error. My GIT remote is GITHUB so no need ssh keys to pull.

Comment: Check your error log at /var/log/httpd/error_log (this is default, it may change). If you do not know how, I recommend tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log --- then visit the page. Not all errors will be displayed even with error_display on.

Comment: I know this question is old, sorry for reviving it, just stumbled across it: `shell_exec` returns `null` if an error occurs, but doesn't display it. You can use [`exec`](http://php.net/exec) to get the output and error code. I explained a possible error due to different webserver-user here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52019553/7362396

Answer (score 1):

Probably *git pull* is throwing an error but the errors are not printed by default. To fix this change this line

```
$output = shell_exec('git pull');
```

for this one:

```
$output = shell_exec('git pull 2>&1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it weird you get no output nothing...

do you have  root access?

try as root in the right folder: sudo -u apache git pull

see if you get any output then.

Comment: this's what I got :
    # sudo -u apache git pull
    sudo: unknown user: apache
    sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Answer (score 0):

You should add following line to `/etc/sudoers`

```
apache2 ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

This allows apache to execute git as root and therefore access the files

then call git command (proper executable location is preferred)

```
shell_exec('sudo /usr/bin/git pull /path/to/your/repo');
```

Comment: No helps, it's still blank :(

Comment: You will need to provide more code and details for us to see where the issue will be.
- whats your current working directory
- a bit more code around
- have you tried to use any other command execution php functions?
-...