# ERROR: Repository not found whilst running git pull via shell_exec on php script

Tags: php, git, shell-exec

I have set up ssh keys properly and added them to my github account . Whenever I ssh into the server and run git pull , everything runs normally and it pulls changes from the repository . However I have a deploy script that runs git pull via shell_exec() but it returns this error;

```
origin  git@github.com:sayopaul/autodeploy-tutorial.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:sayopaul/autodeploy-tutorial.git (push)
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Does PHP (or the webserver) run as the same user that you use when you SSH into the server. If not, it may not have access to your users SSH keys to authenticate vs GitHub.

Comment: Hmm thank you very much . This makes sense . PHP (webserver) runs as the user www-data and the user I use to SSH into the server is different . However I would expect that the error would be " Permission denied ( Public Key ) " if it was an issue with the SSH key .Please Is there a way I could change the user for the PHP script inorder to test ?

Comment: It's kinda encoded in *"make sure you have the correct access rights"* but I agree, the error could be formulated better. There are a few things I can think of, an easy one being to utilize [`sudo`](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo): Add this rule: `www-data ALL=(yourotheruser) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git`, then invoke git like: `sudo -u yourotheruser git pull`

Comment: The sudo approach only runs the one command as the other user (you could further limit the potential damage done by allowing access only to a custom script that runs `git pull` in the correct directory). The other approach is to change the user the PHP process itself is running under, either using `php-fpm` or the [`ITK MPM`](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/).

Comment: Hello there !! It works ! I finally got it to work using your advice . You were right , the user www-data did not have access to the ssh keys . I ran "sudo visudo" and added the rule www-data ALL=(yourotheruser) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git like you said and then invoked git with  sudo -u yourotheruser git pull  and now it runs successfully . Thank you very much ! 

Comment: Great. I added the solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP (the webserver) likely **doesn't run as the same user** you use when you SSH into the server. Thus, it doesn't have access/permission / **doesn't use the correct SSH keys** to authenticate vs GitHub.

I can think of 2 easy solutions:

---

- Utilize **[`sudo`](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo)**:

Add this rule in the sudo-conf (`sudo visudo`) to allow the user `www-data` to run (only) `/usr/bin/git` as `yourotheruser`:

```
www-data ALL=(yourotheruser) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

Now you can invoke `git` using:

```
sudo -u yourotheruser git pull
```

***Security advise:*** To limit the potential damage done if someone manages to execute arbitrary code through `www-data`:

Create a script owned by `yourotheruser` (and not writeable by others), e.g. `/home/yourotheruser/deploy.sh` with the contents:

```bash
cd /path/to/repo
git pull
```

And allow the `sudo` access only to this script. This way, no other `git` action than `pull` in the intended directory can be performed.

---

- Change **the user PHP itself is executed** with:

  - Use `php-fpm`
  - Use the [`ITK MPM`](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/)

Comment: Thank you very much once again ! Spent so much time on it and I am so glad it works now . 